# "katana_driver" connectivity with Katana Arm 6M180

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am struggling with the katana_driver in ROS (hydro) for the 6M180 arm. When I try to launch the Katana node, I get the following error:

process[katana-3]: started with pid [24264]
[ INFO] [1414017395.500394067]: trying to connect to katana (serial port: /dev/ttyS0) ...
[ERROR] [1414017395.500853297]: Exception during initialization: 'Cannot get/set attributes on '/dev/ttyS0''

### .
.

Does it mean the arm has to be connected serially? Or I will have to use a USB to serial converter because I have connected it via USB. But here is another question, isn't that USB treated as a network device?

Could anyone please help how to connect the arm to the laptop in order for katana_driver to work properly?

Any comments/suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you,

Muhammad Tufail

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195669/%22katana_driver%22-connectivity-with-katana-arm-6m180/) by [tufail](https://answers.ros.org/users/4381/tufail/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is how to connect to the Katana via USB. These instructions are tested on our Katana 450 6M90a with an internal control board (i.e., a "base" to mount the arm). You are indeed correct that when you connect the Katana via USB, it acts as a USB network device.

- Connect the arm via USB and switch it on.
- Since the arm doesn't have a DHCP server, you need to configure the network manually. Open up NetworkManager and create a new connection for the USB network adapter interface:

  - IP address: 192.168.1.* , where * is anything in the range [2-255], e.g. 192.168.1.77
  - network mask: 255.255.255.0
  - no gateway (0.0.0.0)
- The arm should now respond to `ping 192.168.1.1`. If it doesn't, don't continue and fix this problem first.
- Make sure that the katana parameters are properly set: `use_serial = false` and `ip = "192.168.1.1"` (see the [katana wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/katana#Parameters) ). These are the defaults, but e.g. `katana_300_6m180.launch` changes these defaults.

If you still have problems, please edit your question and include the following information:

- What Katana arm do you have, exactly? Is it e.g. a Katana 300 6M180? Does it have an internal/external control board or none?
- What ROS version are you using?
- What's your `katana_driver` branch? Did you make any local changes?
- What launch files are you starting?

---

**Answers to your reply:**

> Error when launching katana.launch: which first says "trying to connect to katana (serial port:/dev/ttyS0) and then says cannot get/set attributes on '/dev/ttyS0'.

Edit the `katana_300_6m180.launch` file and remove the line where it says `use_serial` (or set the param to false).

> Error when launching katana_300_6m180.launch: says the parameter katana_type was not set!

You shouldn't launch that file directly; instead, use `katana.launch`, then this error doesn't occur. That file includes `katana_300_6m180.launch`.

> fatal error: armadillo: No such file or directory

Just do the following:

```
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
rosdep install katana_driver
```

If that doesn't work, just do the following directly:

```
sudo apt-get install libarmadillo-dev
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tufail](https://answers.ros.org/users/4381/tufail/) on 2014-11-04**:
Everything worked fine. Thanks.

I didn't have to set the `use_serial` param to false as the katana I have is 400 6M180 (not 300). So for I have been setting the `KATANA_TYPE` environment variable to `katana_300_6m180` which was wrong.

I installed the `libarmadillo-dev' and rosmake worked too.

**Comment by [João Almeida](https://answers.ros.org/users/24347/jo%C3%A3o-almeida/) on 2015-10-08**:
Hi Martin,
I have exactly this problem. My computer doesn't have a serial port so I'm using a Prolific Serial to USB converter to connect to the Katana.
However I didn't understand exactly how to set up the network interface for the USB port. Could you please try to explain me exactly how to do it?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-10-09**:
I guess if you're using a serial to USB converter, it should show up as a serial port, right? So you shouldn't set up any network interface, but set use_serial = true.

**Comment by [João Almeida](https://answers.ros.org/users/24347/jo%C3%A3o-almeida/) on 2015-10-13**:
Thank you Martin! We fixed the problem by creating a symbolic link between the '/dev/ttys0/ and the '/dev/ttyUSB0'.